# Can FindComponent Be Used To Find A Ruler on a PageControl Created at Runtime

Tags: delphi

Actually I am using a ImageEN TRulerBox and a TAdvOfficePager (TMS) rather than a TPageControl; however, the TAdvOfficePager functions the same way as a TPageControl aside from property names.

Two ImageEN TRulerBoxes and a TImageENView are added to a TAdvOfficePage at runtime.  The ruler orientation is set by the RulerDir property of the TRulerBox. Can FindComponent be used to find a HorzontalRulerBox and a VerticalRulerBox?

The controls are created at runtime like this:

```
procedure TFormMain.AddPage;
var
  AdvOfficePage: TAdvOfficePage;
  PixelPanel: TPanel;
begin
  AdvOfficePage := TAdvOfficePage.Create( Self );
  AdvOfficePage.Parent := AdvOfficePager1;
  AdvOfficePager1.AddAdvPage( AdvOfficePage );
  AdvOfficePage.AdvOfficePager := AdvOfficePager1;
  AdvOfficePage.Caption := 'ImageEnView ' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount );
  AdvOfficePage.TabHint := 'ImageEnView ' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount );
  TopPanel := TPanel.Create( Self );
  TopPanel.Parent := AdvOfficePage;
  TopPanel.Height := 34;
  TopPanel.Align := alTop;
  TopPanel.Color := $00fcebdc;
  TopPanel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  TopPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  PixelPanel := TPanel.Create( TopPanel );
  PixelPanel.Parent := TopPanel;
  PixelPanel.Height := 40;
  PixelPanel.Width := 34;
  PixelPanel.Caption := 'Pix';
  PixelPanel.Align := alLeft;
  PixelPanel.Color := $00fdf3eb;
  PixelPanel.ParentBackground := False;
  PixelPanel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  PixelPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  HorzontalRulerBox := TRulerBox.Create( TopPanel );
  HorzontalRulerBox.Name := 'HorzontalRulerBox' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount );
  HorzontalRulerBox.Parent := TopPanel;
  HorzontalRulerBox.Align := alClient;
  HorzontalRulerBox.BackGround := $00fdf3eb;
  HorzontalRulerBox.RulerColor := $00fdf3eb;
  HorzontalRulerBox.GripBaseDim := 1;
  HorzontalRulerBox.RulerDir := rdHorizontal;
  LeftPanel := TPanel.Create( Self );
  LeftPanel.Parent := AdvOfficePage;
  LeftPanel.Width := 30;
  LeftPanel.Align := alLeft;
  LeftPanel.Color := $00fdf3eb;
  LeftPanel.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  LeftPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  VerticalRulerBox := TRulerBox.Create( LeftPanel );
  VerticalRulerBox.Name := 'VerticalRulerBox' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount );
  VerticalRulerBox.Parent := LeftPanel;
  VerticalRulerBox.Align := alClient;
  VerticalRulerBox.BackGround := $00fdf3eb;
  VerticalRulerBox.GripBaseDim := 1;
  VerticalRulerBox.RulerDir := rdVertical;
  VerticalRulerBox.BackGround := $00fdf3eb;
  VerticalRulerBox.RulerColor := $00fdf3eb;
  ImageENView := TImageEnView.Create( Self );
  ImageENView.Parent := AdvOfficePage;
  ImageENView.Left := 0;
  ImageENView.Top := 0;
  ImageENView.Align := alClient;
  ImageENView.Center := True;
  ImageENView.Visible := True;
  ImageENView.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  ImageENView.MouseInteract := [ miSelect ];
  AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage := AdvOfficePage;
end;
```

If FindComponent can not be used how do you get the handle to each of the two rulers at runtime?  I hope I have asked this question correctly and the information provided is clear.

I tried this but it returns nil:

```
function TFormMain.GetHorzontalRuler: TRulerBox;
// find horzontal TRulerBox component on a TPanel on a TAdvOfficePage
var
  rb: TRulerBox;
begin
  rb := AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage.FindComponent( 'HorzontalRulerBox' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.ActivePageIndex ) )
    as TRulerBox;
  if Assigned( rb ) then
    Result := rb
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

**NEW: - this works**

```
function TFormMain.GetHorzRuler: TRulerBox;
var
  tp: TPanel;
  rb: TRulerBox;
begin
  Result := nil;
  tp := FindComponent( 'TopPanel' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.ActivePageIndex + 1 ) ) as TPanel;
  if Assigned( tp ) then
  begin
    rb := TRulerBox( tp.FindComponent( 'HorzontalRulerBox' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.ActivePageIndex + 1 ) ) );
    if Assigned( rb ) then
      Result := rb;
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

function TFormMain.GetVertRuler: TRulerBox;
var
  tp: TPanel;
  rb: TRulerBox;
begin
  Result := nil;
  tp := FindComponent( 'LeftPanel' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.ActivePageIndex + 1 ) ) as TPanel;
  if Assigned( tp ) then
  begin
    rb := TRulerBox( tp.FindComponent( 'VerticalRulerBox' + IntToStr( AdvOfficePager1.ActivePageIndex + 1 ) ) );
    if Assigned( rb ) then
      Result := rb;
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made `TopPanel` the owner of `HorzontalRulerBox` (btw, it's HorIzontal :) ), so you need to search it with `FindComponent` instead, but you'll have to first search `TFormMain` for `TopPanel`,and give `TopPanel` a name in your code.

```
var
  TP: TPanel;
  rb: TRulerBox;
begin
  TP := FindComponent('TopPanel') as TPanel;
  if Assigned(TP) then
  begin
    rb := TP.FindComponent('HorzontalRulerBox` + IntToStr(whatever));
    if Assigned(rb) then
      // Work with ruler box
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why such downvote, I don't understand.Upvoted to counter (if I could I'd +2 ).

Comment: @FabricioAraujo, thanks. I have someone who is following me around downvoting without any explanation. They downvoted 23 posts in 3 minutes yesterday; apparently they don't know that juvenile behavior like that doesn't work. All the rep I lost was restored in less than 24 hours, but they don't get theirs back. At least I have the courage to explain why I'm downvoting. :)

Comment: Ah, the anonymous downvoter strikes again. Just got another downvote on a 2 1/2 year old post that received 30+ upvotes, with no comment, right after this one was downvoted. :)

Comment: @Ken White: +1 for your complete solution, and I think the downvoter will lost its interrest quickly !

Comment: @TridenT: Thanks. The sad thing is that I try really hard to be helpful here. I have no problem if someone downvotes me, as long as they explain why so I can learn (or defend myself) from it. I try to give others that courtesy. I appreciate the support. :)

Comment: Everybody on the Delphi tag knows of your answers and how hard you try to help. Your 17.5k of rep are reflection of that - and a lone wolf which sport is downvote you shows only envy... The cheesy quote "The streght of your envy = speed of my success" applies here hehehe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The function `FindComponent` **must** be used by the **Owner** component.
The owner can be different than the parent, so be carefull.

In your example, the owner component is maybe the form, or the OfficePager.
Try replacing `AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage` by self (to reference the form) or `AdvOfficePager1` - I don't use these components so I'm not sure.